# Change currency of two fields based on known USD aggregate values

Tags: vba, excel, currency

I have quite a macro challenge and am going on the assumption my problem would be best solved using a macro as opposed to a formula.

I have an Excel sheet set up with line item records. Each record has the following fields:

> Order Number,  Product number, price, quantity, extended price, order total.

There can be from one to ten records per Order Number (makes this problem harder). Additionally, each record of the same Order Number will have the same `order total` as well. Currently, the `price` and `extended price` are not in USD, however the `order total` is. My goal is to convert the `price` and `extended price` to USD using the `order total` (which *is* in USD).

For each of the set or records for each Order Number I want to take the `order total` (which I can get from any of the set), divide by the sum of the `extended price`s, and then multiply each `extended price` and `price` for the set by that. To convert those to USD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With formulae is possible. Assuming `Order Number` is a label in ColumnA and other data follows from there, in H2 and copied down to suit:

```
 =SUMIF(A:A,A2,E:E)
```

should return the extended price by order number in non US currency.

In I2 and copied down to suit:

```
=F2/H2
```

should return the appropriate conversion factor.

Since this is computed, copy ColumnI to ColumnJ with Paste Special..., Values.

Copy ColumnJ, select Columns C and E (`price` and `extended price`) and Paste Special... with Operation Multiply.

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will help:
If you want to do the exact currency conversion operation using macros,
Try sample like this:

```
    Sub conversion()
Dim a, b As Long
b = 50.55
a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value
b = a / 50.55
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = "$" & b
End Sub
```

here a is the total of price and the extended price and b is the converted USD value.
else if you want to change the format alone you can go with format cells option in excel